# Prove $\exp{\frac{a+b}{2}}>\frac{1}{2}(\exp a + \exp b), a,b\in \mathbb{R},a \ne b$

Tags: real-analysis

Self-studying. Tools I considered and used: the rules for $\exp$, $\log$, the fact that $a>b\iff \log a > \log b$, i.e., $\exp$ is an increasing function, derivatives of same, Taylor expansions of left and right hand sides of the inequality and the ability to apply the binomial theorem where possible. I tried these tools in various combinations without the desired conclusion yet.

What would be some ways to approach this proof? (If you want to supply a proof, perhaps you could in the first paragraph provide hints to the approach and then in a second (spoiler) paragraph provide the proof, or something similar, that way I can hide my own view of the proof and first attempt the hints).

Comment: The inequality is the other way around, because exp is *convex.*

Comment: The book I am using actually has it the way I wrote it, probably errata I would suppose. J. Klein & G. Reeb, M.P.C., Book A, Chapter 2, problem 3 (in French). "Montrer que, quels que soient $a$ et $b$ $(a \ne b)$..." and then the inequality I wrote followed by "Interpreter graphiquement", interpret graphically. The book's solution was a hint: Refer to the chapter on Taylor series.

Comment: A major tool you left off the list is _convexity_. (As we see from one of the answers below) convexity is where really a lot of inequalities come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant $$ \exp\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \color{red}< \frac{\exp(a)+\exp(b)}{2} $$You can use the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

> Specifically, set $x = \exp(a), y = \exp(b)$. Then using AM-GM, we get that $\sqrt{xy} < \frac{x+y}{2}$

Comment: Your AM-GM inequality is the wrong way around.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$y=e^x \implies y'=e^x>0$$ and $$y''=e^x>0$$

Thus your function is increasing and concave upward, that is the straight segment connecting $(a,e^a)$ and $(b,e^b)$ stays above the graph of $y=e^x$ for $x\in (a,b)$

in particular for the midpoint $\frac {a+b}{2}$ you get $$e^{\frac {a+b}{2}}<\frac {e^a+e^b}{2}$$

The stronger result is for a convex function we have for each $0<\lambda<1$

$$f(\lambda a +(1-\lambda) b)<\lambda f(a) +(1-\lambda) f(b)$$

This was a case of $\lambda =1/2$

Comment: Thank you, this actually fits the knowledge the book has provided to this point. It hadn't discussed the AM-GM inequality yet. I'd give you more points if I could.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your attention and understanding. I am glad that you liked it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a\not =b$;

$(e^{a/2}-e^{b/2})^2 > 0$;

$e^a -2e^{a/2}e^{b/2} +e^b >0$;

$e^a+e^b >2e^{a/2}e^{b/2}=2e^{\frac{a+b}{2}}$.

Comment: Clever. Curious, did you start with the result and work backwards to find the beginning true statement? I like this technique.

Comment: Joe.Not so very clever:)$(u-v)^2 \ge 0$ yields $u^2+v^2 \ge 2uv$.If $u,v \ge 0$, set $u=√x,v=√y$ and you get $x+y \ge 2√x√y$ (note $x,y \ge 0$), AM-GM.